# modular arithmetic proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers and $x= 3y^2 -z^2$.  Prove that $x\not\equiv1\mod4$.

My thoughts: So I am not sure the route that can prove this. I am trying to just use the simple stuff to set me up.  I started with saying if $x\equiv1\mod4$ you would have $4|x-1$ and there will exist an integer, say $t$, where $x-1 = 4t$.  I then solved for $x$ just because the other equation was in terms of $x$.  So from that we would have $x=4t+1$.  Not sure if I am on the right track here or what I can do with what I have.

Answer (score 3):

The base is small enough for this problem that we can use proof by exhaustion by letting $y,z \equiv 0,1,2,3 \pmod 4$. And in fact, because $0^2 \equiv 2^2 \pmod 4$ and $1^2 \equiv 3^2 \pmod 4$, you only have to check $4$ different cases:

1. $y \equiv 0, z \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 0^2 - 0^2 \equiv 0$
2. $y \equiv 0, z \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 0^2 - 1^2 \equiv 3$
3. $y \equiv 1, z \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 1^2 - 0^2 \equiv 3$
4. $y \equiv 1, z \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 1^2 - 1^2 \equiv 2$

And none of these are $1$.

Comment: I changed (\mod 4) to \pmod 4. That way instead of seeing $(\mod 4)$ you see $\pmod 4$.  (If the number has more than one digit you need braces, so \pmod41 appears as $\pmod41$, but \pmod{41} appears as $\pmod{41}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: so because of the "in fact" statements you dont have to do any number combinations with 0,2 or 1,3? what about both y,z being 3 or 2, or the combination of 2,3?

Comment: To clarify, because $0^2 \equiv 2^2 \pmod{4}$, the first case ($y \equiv 0, z \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$) includes and yields the same result as $y \equiv 0, z \equiv 2$, $y \equiv 2, z \equiv 0$, and $y \equiv 2, z \equiv 2$. Similar logic applies for $1$ and $3$.

Comment: alright. I am having a little trouble understanding how you can quickly assume that.  Is it just because if you have those equal it doesn't really matter what coefficients are in front of this, for this example 3 and 1?

Comment: So really there are only three cases because we know 0^2 IS CONGRUENT to 0^2 (mod4)?

Comment: $y \equiv 0, z \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 0^2 - 0^2 \equiv 0 \equiv 0$

$y \equiv 0, z \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 0^2 - 2^2 \equiv -4 \equiv 0$

$y \equiv 2, z \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 2^2 - 0^2 \equiv 12 \equiv 0$

$y \equiv 2, z \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow 3y^2 - z^2 \equiv 3 \cdot 2^2 - 2^2 \equiv 8 \equiv 0$

We are considering the possible values of $y$ and $z$. Don't worry about the coefficients. We are essentially reducing $\{0,1,2,3\},\{0,1,2,3\}$ - $16$ cases - to $\{0,1\},\{0,1\}$ - $4$.

Comment: but also 2^2 mod4 is not congruent to 1^2 mod4 even though they yield the same result. or is that another case

Comment: but just because they are equal doesn't necessarily mean it wouldn't be one

Answer (score 1):

For the congruence to hold, $y$ and $z$ must have fifferent parities.

If $y$ is odd and $z$ is even, then $y^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and therefore $3y^2\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, and therefore $3y^2-z^2\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

If $y$ is even and $z$ is odd, then $z^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and therefore $3y^2-z^2\equiv -1\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

**Remark:** We can *symmetrize*, by noting that $3y^2\equiv -y^2\pmod{4}$, and therefore $3y^2-z^2\equiv -(y^2+z^2)\pmod{4}$. The advantage is that $y^2+z^2$ is symmetric in $y$ and $z$, so without loss of generality there is only one case to consider.

Answer (score 0):

mod $\,4\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{{-}1} \not\equiv -x \equiv  y^2\!+x^2 \equiv \{0,1\}\!+\!\{0,1\} \equiv \{0,1,2\}\ \ $ **QED**